# Tried to empty massive # of files in Trash "rm -rf ~/.Trash/* " BUT GET -bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long

Tags: linux, mac

Tried to empty massive # of files in Trash with this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

But I get this error message:

```
-bash: /bin/rm: Argument list too long.
```

Obviously, when the OS expands the file list there are too many files.

Comment: linux or Mac? You tagged both with no further detail.

Comment: why delete a folder to recreate it? just remove all files instead: ```find . -type f -name "FILE-TO-FIND" -exec rm -f {} \;```

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests, the command can only be up to a certain length. You can run `getconf ARG_MAX` to find out what this is - my Linux system reports ~2MiB (that's a *lot* of filenames!)

To resolve this, you can use a number of options to reduce the size of the arguments passed at any one time.

### Change Directory

In your case, because the glob `~/.Trash/*` will expand out to `~/.Trash/file1.txt ~/.Trash/file2.txt ~/.Trash/file3.txt ...`, you can easily save a lot of argument size by simply changing directory first:

```bsh
cd ~/.Trash/
rm -rf *
```

### Split the Wildcard

If you have files that match different patterns, you can delete some each time. For example: all the PDFs, then all the text files, then everything else.

```bsh
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*.pdf
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*.txt
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

### Use `find`

`find` will process each file as it is located in the filesystem. The `-mindepth 1` option is given so that the `.Trash` directory iself isn't deleted too.

```bsh
find ~/.Trash/ -mindepth 1 -delete
```

### Use `xargs`

In this specific situation, `xargs` is a bit redundant (as `find` can do everything you need), but if you wanted to use `grep`, `sed`, etc... to pick out the files that you want to delete with more complex patterns than `find` can support, then the following will work:

```bsh
find ~/.Trash/ -mindepth 1 -name '*.log' | grep -E 'specific_[0-9a-f]{4}\.log' | xargs rm
```

One of the roles of `xargs` is to ensure that it passes "*manageable*" argument chunks to the nominated command... so `rm` may actually be run multiple times with a different set of arguments each time.

---

*NOTE:* with globbing (i.e: wildcards) giving `~/.Trash/*` doesn't actually say "*match everything in `~/.Trash/`*" - it'll miss all of the files and directories that begin with a dot... giving `~/.Trash/.*` as well will actually expand out to include `.` and `..` too, which isn't what you wanted at all (sometimes you'll be protected)... `find ${DIR} -mindepth 1` is the superior option here if you really wanted to "*match everything in `~/.Trash/`*".

Answer (score 1):

If this is really on a Mac, as indicated by one of the "tags" used on this question, just ask the Finder to empty the Trash.  It probably uses an approach similar to the `find` command in a couple of the answers, so it shouldn't run into the same wildcard expansion as you hit.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
 find ~/.Trash/* -delete
```

src:

- https://ss64.com/osx/find.html
- https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: This will probably delete `.Trash` too...

Comment: ... putting the wildcard there will break `find`